# Using Image.ptr<double>(0); with color image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am studying GrabCut in OpenCV (c++) and I stuck with this line

```
coefs = model.ptr<double>(0);
mean = coefs + componentsCount;
cov = mean + 3*componentsCount;
```

where 
*model* is Matrix 
*coefs*, *mean*, and *cov* are double* 
*componentsCount* is a constant integer

I wonder what coefs will be? Is it is RGB values or something else? (the result of the following code)

```
model.ptr<double>(0);
```

And what happens in line

```
cov = mean + 3*componentsCount;
```

Thank you for answer!! :)

Comment: To use `ptr<double>`, your image should be `Mat1d` = `CV_64F` type of `Mat`, I think. If your image is 3-channel, consider using `Vec3d`

Comment: If you provide the code you're using, we can give a more detailed answer

Comment: @Miki A complete source code of GrabCut is here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp

Comment: @Berriel I think so, but from my understanding, *model* is color image. A complete source code of GrabCut is here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp and an example of using GrabCut is here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/grabcut.cpp

Comment: @PandarianLd yeah, I know :D. Edit the link into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mat `model` is not a color image, but the model for the [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp).

The GMM has these private memmbers:

```
Mat model;     
double* coefs; 
double* mean;  
double* cov;
```

`model` a single channel double matrix (`CV64FC1`), with 1 row and number of columns equals to `modelSize*componentsCount`, where

```
componentsCount = 5 // line 60
modelSize = 13 // 3/*mean*/ + 9/*covariance*/ + 1/*component weight*/    // line 89
```

This data are stores in the matrix `model` with this layout:

```
cw0, cw1, cw4, m00, m01, m02, m10, ..., m42, c00, c11, ...
^              ^                             ^
coefs = model.ptr<double>(0)                 ^
                                             mean + 3*componentsCount
               ^                             
               ^                            
               coefs + componentsCount
```

where:

```
cw<i>    is the weight of the i-th component 
m<i><j>  is the j-th dimension mean of the i-th component
c<i><j>  is the j-th dimension covariance of the i-th component
```

So:

```
coefs = model.ptr<double>(0);   // points at the start of the weights into model
mean = coefs + componentsCount; // points at the start of the means into model
cov = mean + 3*componentsCount; // points at the start of the covariances into model
```

`ptr<double>()` just return a `double*` at the beginning of line 0, i.e. the start of the data into the matrix. It's equivalent to `(double*)model.data`.

Basically, `coefs`, `mean` and `cov` are just shortcuts to get the appropriate data into the `model`.

Comment: 1.How do you know that the model is CV32FC1 (from the code?)? ///
2 In the model, you said that m01, m02, m03. mij is mean of index i and j. Why it starts new row (i) when j = 2? How do you know?

Comment: @PandarianLd 1) It's CV_64FC1. Yes, from the code. But you also have a assertion error if it's not. 2) 3 mean, one for each color channel.

Comment: Ah!! I got it!! But I still have some question about the code `Mat _bgdSamples( (int)bgdSamples.size(), 3, CV_32FC1, &bgdSamples[0][0] );` (Line 380 in grabcut.cpp).  What is the value of `bgdSamples.size()` and what is the value of `_bgdSamples` after assign `&bgdSamples[0][0]`?

Comment: You create `bgdSamples` few lines above. Its size is just the number of pixels that are marked as `GC_BGD ` or `GC_PR_BGD `. You just wrap the `std::vector<Vec3f>` into a matrix, with `Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)` constructor. If you have further questions, please consider asking a new question.